# PySide6 QUiLoader doesn't show window

Tags: python, pyside6

It is a simple coding.
I tried the code below which is almost same example in the QT for Python website.

see the website below **option B**.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html

but when I execute the code below, it doesn't show the window and keep running until I stop.
I put print codes in the code to figure out where it is and it is loader = QUiLoader().
print('d') is not executed.

No error messeges. It is just keep running without showing window.

ui file is okay. I converted .ui file to .py file and it works well. also when I clicked ui file, it shows Qt design well.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice

print('a')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


ui_file_name = 'imported_from_design.ui'
ui_file = QFile(ui_file_name)
print('b')

if not ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    print("Can not open the file {}, the error is {}".format(ui_file_name, ui_file.errorString()))
    sys.exit(-1)

print('c')

loader = QUiLoader()

print('d')
window = loader.load(ui_file)


ui_file.close()

if not window:
    print(loader.errorString())
    sys.exit(-1)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
print('e')
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Linux using Qt 6.6.1 and PySide-6.6.1. Please edit your question and state the *specific* platform and versions of Qt6/PySide6 are you using, and also show the ui file you are testing with.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem and @user23331262 is correct (partially). I may just misunderstood his answer.

The reason for the problem is (probably a bug, but) the QUiLoader object needs to be initialized BEFORE the QApplication. I don't know why, again, that's probably a bug.

Anyway, the following should work:

```
loader = QUiLoader() # NOTICE: Initialized before "QApplication"
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = loader.load("path/to/file", None)
app.exec()
```

For classes you can either have a global loader, load UI files manually or pass the loader in

Comment: Exactly, you save my day.

I thought PySide are from Qt official, should be better than PyQt, but it looks like the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and I fixed it after searching online.
it might be just a bug of Pyside6 with version of 6.6.0 or 6.6.1.
solution:
make the definition using "app = QApplication(sys.argv)" after Generating instances based on class of QUiloader().